# Missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed in corrplot

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I received this

```
Error in if (min(corr) < -1 - .Machine$double.eps || max(corr) > 1 + .Machine$double.eps) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

and I am not sure what it means. I have a missing value in my data and would like to remove that row of data. My previous code for getting a corrplot was

```
library(corrplot)
C <- cor(SIMPIN_Data)
corrplot(C, method="number", use="complete.obs")
```

Help? I am very new to R.

My data looks like this

```
 1-Response time 1-Accuracy 2-Response time 2-Accuracy 3-Response Time 3-Accuracy
1        500         .80             200          .60          100         .99
2        550          NA             250          .30          900         .50
3        550         .20             250          .30          900         .50
```

Comment: If would help if you included sample input data to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Very likely that `min(corr,na.rm=TRUE)` (and the same for the `max` part) will solve the issue. R is telling that the result of the `if` statement is `NA` and so it cannot procede. The `min` and `max` functions return `NA` if an element of the vector is `NA`.

Comment: Your correaltion matrix has missing (NA) in it, and corrplot will not work with missing. You have used the `use="complete.obs"` in the wrong place  - use it in the `cor` function.

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this known corrplot issue **"Enable to plot a matrix with NA"**. See https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/issues/7

The problem was indeed in `min(corr,na.rm=TRUE)` and `max(corr,na.rm=TRUE)` as suggested by @nicola

You can download the latest version from github:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("taiyun/corrplot")
```